# SQLite batch update of a column in a table

Tags: sqlite

I am using SQLite and have the following SQL Statement which updates column active with true for just row 28.

```
update "customer" set "active"='true' where rowid=28
```

What I would like to do is batch update the entire customer table, active column to true. I would have thought a loop was the best method, but I don't think sqlite supports loops. Anyone advise me how I can update a column in a table so all the records contain the value the in them?

Thanks

Comment: Just leave off the where clause; the update will be applied to every row in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update "customer" set "active"='true'
```

will do the job (just don't specify a where)